# How to store two versions of the row in the same Oracle table

Tags: oracle, row, versions

I am working on creating an application with an Oracle database as data backend.

The idea is to store two version of a row in the table: one is edited and the second one is before image of the row. When the edited row is approved, the before image is replaced with the edited row, else the edited row is deleted.

To do so, I added `change_id` into all the primary, foreign keys. The `change_id` addition is done on the application side. I would like to know if this is the right approach or should I follow some other approach?

Comment: and what if you adding an changed_flag column, with 'Y' or 'N' values?

Comment: StackOverflow is for tactical "why doesn't my code work" questions. For design questions I think that [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Thomas, I wanted to store some useful info, such as a task_id, which changed the row.

Comment: and what about Slowly Changing Dimensions?  http://datawarehouse4u.info/SCD-Slowly-Changing-Dimensions.html

Comment: @Thomas, never heard about, quick look at the document you referred to shows that I am using similar approach. So indeed, this seems to be acceptable. But as I said earlier, I shall be using task_id to add more info on under which process this has changed.